# How to update parameters without reloading the view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have been trying to do this.  I want to change state because my parameters have changed, but nothing else about my state has changed, so I don't want to reload the view. It is expensive, and it causes a flash.  I really just want to get an event that the `$stateParams` have changed, and go with that.

The only way I can figure out how to update the params goes like this:

```
$state.go($state.current, {param: value});
```

This works ([codepen](http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/uHAKF)), except my controller/view gets reloaded.  Again, I don't want that.

I came up with a hack, but I don't like it.  First, I need to tell it to not notify:

```
$state.go($state.current, {param, value}, {notify: false});
```

I'can try to watch for changes on `$stateParams`, but the change never happens.  Instead, I create a global controller which attaches `$stateParams` to the `$rootScope`.  Then from my view controller, I can `$watch` for changes on `$scope.$stateParams`.

This works ([codepen](http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/btdDo)), but it is really messy.  It seems like there must be a better way to handle this, but I can't find a better way.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about $watching $location.search() instead?

Codepen fork: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mbsgr

Updated $watch function:

```
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $location.search();
      }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue != oldValue) {
          alert('act on state param change');
        }
      });
```

Comment: Seems like a better alternative.  I'm still looking to see if there is a better supported way, but I like that better than my other options.  Good idea.